# Problema em seleção SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Por que mesmo eu filtrando para retornar apenas o fabricante fiat, fica retornando outros valores?

```
 SELECT FABRICANTE, MODELO, VALOR_DIARIA FROM VEICULO 
    WHERE VALOR_DIARIA = (SELECT MIN(VALOR_DIARIA) FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT')
```

Resultado:

```
FABRICANTE                     MODELO                         VALOR_DIARIA
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------
VOLKSWAGEN                     GOL                                      80
FIAT                           PALIO                                    80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você utilizou uma subconsulta para filtrar os valores, o que não é necessário. Neste caso, o valor da diária da FIAT é igual ao da VOLKSWAGEN e, como a subconsulta retorna "80", traz as duas.
O correto seria simplesmente:

```
SELECT FABRICANTE, MODELO, VALOR_DIARIA FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT';
```

O ideal é que você utilize um filtro que usem campos que sejam chaves primárias e evite filtro diretamente em texto para encontrar valores exatos. De qualquer maneira isto vai funcionar.

No caso de precisar escolher o de menor valor, você pode adicionar mais um critério, tipo assim:

```
SELECT FABRICANTE, MODELO, VALOR_DIARIA FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT' AND VALOR_DIARIA = (SELECT MIN(VALOR_DIARIA) FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT');
```

Ou outro critério qualquer priorizando o registro que você precisa.

Pode ser feito também a limitação de linhas, forçando o banco a trazer a primeira linha. Tipo assim:

```
SELECT FABRICANTE, MODELO, VALOR_DIARIA FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT' AND VALOR_DIARIA = (SELECT MIN(VALOR_DIARIA) FROM VEICULO WHERE FABRICANTE = 'FIAT') LIMIT 1
```

Abraço!

Comment: mas o exercício pede para eu presentar o fabricante e o modelo do veículo com menor valor de diária e eu queria filtrar para aparecer apenas o carro da fiat

Comment: Neste caso você terá que usar mais um critério.
Se faça a pergunta: Se houver mais de um com a mesma diária, o que fazer? Apresentar os dois? Priorizar algum?

Comment: haha deu certo amigo, muito obrigado, pelo visto eu não consegui passar da forma correta o que eu quero pro banco, agradeço a atenção!!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Não tem de quê! O que precisar estamos aqui! Abraço!